# How can we utilise the excess pressure in a bubble?

Tags: fluid-statics

In general,the excess pressure in a bubble varies inversely with its radius. In limit of a small bubble the excessive pressure inside the bubble is very high.

My question is that how can we utilise this excess pressure for a large system?

Comment: It would help if you defined what "large" means in terms of bubble size.

Comment: Ex: moving a piston or a pulley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you mean by "utilize" is exploit for the purposes of extracting useful work from it, there is no net useful work in a bubble, no matter what its size. To create the bubble in the first place requires the expenditure of work, so even if you came up with some clever means to extract the pressurized air from inside a microbubble and for example spin a microturbine with it, all you'd get is what you put in to start with, minus frictional losses, etc.

Comment: Doubt: sir, why it can't do work?

Comment: it can do work, but the energy stored in it came from its creation: no free energy here.